# Using dictionary data structure in lex/yacc

Tags: dictionary, yacc, lex

I'm writing an assembler for a microprocessor I'm creating using lex/yacc.

I'd like to implement labels in my assembler code, and I thought a good way to do this would be to have a dictionary of labels in the form {name:line#}. I could then check when inserting a label, if it's already defined, its an error.

So how can I use a dictionary structure in lex/yacc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the various hash table implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Implementations) to find one you like.

Answer (score 0):

For labels? Create a structure with a file pointer, and initialise that to the position of the found label. And when you come across the label declaration, access that pointer and fill that blank with locctr.